# No me crea la session PHP

Tags: php, cookies

tengo un problema con este código.. yo recibo las cookies correctamente pero cuando le quiero asignar esos valores a las sesiones no me las crea y no se porque, alguna idea??

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["idusuario"]) && isset($_COOKIE["marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw"]))
{
   if (is_int($_COOKIE['idusuario'])&& is_int($_COOKIE['marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw']))
   {
      $iduser=$_COOKIE['idusuario'];
      $numero_cookie=$_COOKIE['marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw'];
      //Tengo cookies memorizadas
      //además voy a comprobar que esas variables no estén vacías
      $c= new Conexiones();
      if ($c->ComprobarCookieUser($iduser,$numero_cookie)==0) //no se pudo determinar si es el usuario.. entonces lo mandamos al index para que inicie sesion
      {
         echo "no encontre la cookie";
      }
      else 
      { 
         session_start();
         $_SESSION['idUsuario']=15;
         echo $_SESSION['idUsuario'];
      }
   }
}

//si las cookies estan vacias entonces compruebo si por lo menos inicio sesion sin recordar la misma
else {  if(empty($_SESSION['idUsuario']) && empty($_SESSION['usuario'])) // si las sessiones estan vacias entonces no puede estar en este sitio
       {header("Location:index.php");}

 }
```

ADJUNTO parte del login.php en el cual creo las cookies

```
if($a->ConectarUser($_POST['user'],$_POST['pass'])==1)
    {

        if ($_POST["recordame"]=="1") //es que pidió memorizar el usuario
        {
        //busco el id del usuario que hizo Esto , lo saco del metodo ConectarUser, el cual ya creò una sesion con el idusuario
        $iduser=intval($_SESSION["idUsuario"]);

  //1) creo una marca aleatoria en el registro de este usuario
  //alimentamos el generador de aleatorios
  mt_srand (time());
  //generamos un número aleatorio
  $numero_aleatorio = mt_rand(1000000,999999999);
  //2) meto la marca aleatoria en la tabla de usuario
  //3) ahora meto una cookie en el ordenador del usuario con el identificador del usuario y la cookie aleatoria
  setcookie("idusuario", $iduser , time()+(60*60*24*365),'/');
  setcookie("marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw", $numero_aleatorio, time()+(60*60*24*365),'/');
        $a->cargar_cookie_user($numero_aleatorio,$iduser);

 }
header('Location: ../main.php');

 }
 else
    { echo  '<div style="width:auto;max-width:500px; height:330px;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;background-color: #FFBABA;border: 2px solid #D8000C;"><p style="margin:0 auto; padding: 50px 10px">No se pudo loguear</p><p style="margin:0 auto">Redireccionando..</p></div>';
          header('refresh:3;url=../index.php');
      }
```

Comment: Hola @fer, ¿En qué momento creas las cookies "idusuario" y "marca_aleatoria_usuario_dw"?

Comment: @SolracRagnarockradio hola , ahi agrego ese codigo para que lo veas, saludos

Answer (score 1):

Deberías indicar que error te sale porque este código es correcto (bueno, te faltaría cerrar uno de los corchetes, pero salvo eso que supongo será un error tipográfico, el código está bien).

Comment: te comento, no muestra ningún error, si le pongo echo $_SESSION simplemente no muestra nada, estuve probando con carteles dentro de cada condición y entra a la condición donde debe crear la sesion pero no lo hace

Comment: Incluye el código que falta porque si no, no te puedo decir.

Comment: ahi agrege el else que le corresponde al codigo, saludos